# Best practices for avoiding assignment errors with dependencies?

Tags: typescript

I've got some packages I'm working on. They export Classes. The general notion is that there's a core package that defines datastore behaviors, then a postgres package that implements a datastore for postgres, another one that implements the same thing using a redis store, and so on.

My problem is in my dependency tree, because the base datastore has a dependency on rxjs, and some of the plugin modules *also* reference rxjs. So:

```
+ node modules
+ -- core
     +  rxjs 5.4.0
+ -- postgres
     +  rxjs 5.4.1
```

Unless the core and postgres modules declare a dependency on *exactly* the same version of rxjs, these two different rxjs packages won't get deduped.

They are effectively the same version, but they're not. I get that. I can deal with corner cases there. The problem is that I can no longer say

```
const pgstore: Store = new PostgresStore();
```

because I basically cannot assign a PostgresStore (declared in my postgres package) to a generic Store variable (declared in my core package), because there are two different versions of rxjs in play, and therefore the `Subject<string>` I have stored as a private property on Store ends up being two different kinds of Subject, and those aren't cross-assignable. (e.g., compilation fails because "Subject is not assignable to type Subject, Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.")

I have to imagine that this is not uncommon. What are the best practices (in structuring dependencies, devdependencies, and so on) to avoid this hangup? It basically results in a very brittle installation, and once in a while I have to spend an hour fiddling with npm and my package.json files to get things properly deduped (it also interferes with my ability to use `npm link` for local dev on the dependant packages, because this makes deduping even harder).

Comment: hmm, seems at least part of the answer is: don't use private / protected members. They end up changing typescript from structural to nominative typing (effectively), and this can be seen as "correct but terrible" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One particular solution, outlined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6496#issuecomment-291890115), is to fix problematic declarations by specifically telling typescript what version of things are needed. I've updated my tsconfig.json to include:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"],
    "rxjs": ["node_modules/rxjs"],
    "plump": ["node_modules/plump"],
    "rxjs/*": ["node_modules/rxjs/*"]
  }
}
```

It seems to be solving my problems for now - I'm still able to use `npm link` to work on my plump modules without typescript getting quite upset with me.

Leaving the question open for now, as there may well be a better answer here.